# Add variable to a Map value after a value has been assigned

Tags: java, dictionary

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    double agentID;
    String type;
    double price;
    Set<String> types = new TreeSet<String>();
    Map<Double, Double> agents = new TreeMap<Double, Double>();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);     
    String propertyID;
    double totalPrice = 0;

    System.out.print ("Please enter file name: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        propertyID = in.next();
        type = in.next(); 
        price = in.nextDouble();
        agentID = in.nextDouble();
        type = type.toUpperCase();   
        types.add(type);
        if (agents.containsValue(agentID)) {
            agents.put(agentID, agents.get(agentID)+price);
        }
        else {
            totalPrice = price;
            agents.put(agentID, totalPrice);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(types);
    System.out.println(agents);
}
```

I am trying to update map value of `totalPrice` if the value in `agentID` is already contained in the `agents` map. When I run the program it will output the initial value assigned to the key `agentID` but it will not output the `totalPrice + price`. I have looked over the questions here and looked over the API Docs, but I am not making any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to map the agentId with the price. So I think what you need to use is

```
if (agents.containsKey(agentID)) { ... }
```

See the [official containsKey javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) for more information.

Please try to simplify the code in your questions (remove the file reading and other unneeded info) to make it easier to determine where the problem could be.

Comment: Nailed it!!! I had wondered if that was the issue, but I didn't know that was an option. This would have been fixed like 2 hours ago if I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are checking value instead you should check if agent is available in the map

change

`if (agents.containsValue(agentID))`

to

```
if (agents.containsKey(agentID))
```

since you are using `agentID` as the key here

```
agents.put(agentID, agents.get(agentID)+price);
```

Answer (score 1):

in you TreeMap you have used **agentID as the key** and **totalPirce as value**, so in your code it should be

> agents.containsKey(agentID)

NOT

> agents.containsValue(agentID)

regards
Isuru